# Responsive UI in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8

I'm having trouble trying to develop a responsive UI for Windows Phone 8.

I have a ListBox and I want that the StackPanel that wraps the content always have the same Margin, independent to screen size.

For example: A StackPanel in a screen with a resolution of 480x800, with Margin="10", should have Height="780" and Width="460". But in a resolution of 720x1080, this StackPanel should have Height="1060" and Width="700".

I already tried using MinWidth, MaxWidth, MinHeight and MaxHeight, but nothing seems to work.
The height is always determined according to the ListBox content, not according to the screen size.

Unfortunately I can't attach images for better understanding. I hope I have been clear.

My code:

```
<ListBox Height="450" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <Border Background="{Binding color}" BorderBrush="#03a9f4" Height="62" Width="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding provider}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="15" />
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Foreground="#323232" Text="{Binding name}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="28" Margin="77,-60,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="#323232" Text="{Binding number}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="17" Margin="77,-23,0,0"/>                                                            
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I would appreciate if somebody could tell me how I can make a responsive UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to  `Stretch` your element

```
<StackPanel Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <!-- content -->
</StackPanel>
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.verticalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just note that alignments are defaulted to `Stretch`, so simply removing them will also work.

Comment: Indeed it is a solution.